# Заглушка для картинок при загрузке страницы сайта

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы при загрузке сайта все картинки имели заглушку, но не при скроллинге они подгружались, а именно все картинки просто должны иметь `loading`. Может есть у кого простенький скрипт который это осуществляет.

Заглушку, имеется ввиду, как в лайт боксе, когда скорость интернета маленькая, вместо картинки идет загрузка в виде маленькой gif, а когда картинка полностью загрузится она отображается как и должна.

Comment: Не совсем понял. То есть, вы хотите просто заменить все изображения на заглушку и никакие действия с ними больше не производить?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: А мне кажется всё ясно, вопрос про Lazy Loading. Просто автор не знает этого термина. Можно почитать тут например: http://habrahabr.ru/post/87083/ и воспользоваться например вот этой библиотекой: https://github.com/callmecavs/layzr.js

Comment: Lazy Loading работает с прокруткой, мне нужно чтоб не зависимо от прокрутки во время загрузки сайта вместо картинок был "значок загрузки", в виде gif изображения

Answer (score 1):

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

images.forEach( function( c ){

 c.onload = function(){
        c.loaded = true;
    }

} );

var projectLoad = function(){

  
 loaded = 0;
 loadCount = 0;

 images.forEach( function( c ){

  loadCount++;
  if( c.loaded )
   loaded++;

 } );

 if( loaded !== loadCount ){
  setTimeout( projectLoad, 100 );  //Если не загрузилось, тут код
    }

};
```